# ggplot2 - shade area between two vertical lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` to create some fairly simple scatter plots. I currently have two simple vertical lines using:

```
... + geom_vline(xintercept=159684.186,linetype="dotted",size=0.6)+
geom_vline(xintercept=159683.438,linetype="dotted",size=0.6)+ ...
```

Can anyone tell me how to shade the area between these two lines from the top of the Y axis to the X axis?

Answer (score 72):

You can use `geom_rect`.

```
... + geom_rect(aes(xmin=159683.438, xmax=159684.186, ymin=0, ymax=Inf))
```

The two values for x come from your `geom_vline` calls. using `ymin=0` takes it down to 0; `ymax=Inf` will take it all the way to the top of the axis.  If you want it to go all the way down to the x axis rather than 0, you can use `ymin=-Inf`.

Some notes:

This works best if it is early in the order of geoms so that it gets drawn first/below the other parts (especially the scatterplot data).

You can set the fill color (`fill` aesthetic) outside the `aes` call to a fixed value.  I would also set the transparency (`alpha`) to something like 0.5 so that the stuff behind it (grid lines, most likely, if you put it as the first geom) can still be seen.

Comment: say xaxis are years and you want to shade 1 year over 2. how to do that? aes doesn't support lists for ymin, xmax, ymax attributes

Comment: Thanks. Note that ``fill`` NOT ``color`` is the keyword here!

Comment: @PatrickT Thanks. Clarified that in the answer.

Answer (score 48):

It might be even easier to use `annotate()` for this if you know the coordinates for which region you want to shade. I had some strange rendering problems when I tried to use `geom_rect()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
     annotate("rect", xmin = 3, xmax = 4.2, ymin = 12, ymax = 21,
        alpha = .2)
```

I know it's essentially the same thing; I just happened stumbled on this tidbit from [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/annotate.html).

Comment: I quite like this approach, as it allow me to have colour and size scales.

Comment: Great approach. Multiple `annotate` statement is allowed. As said, `color` and `fill` arguments are easily controlled. `alpha` transparency argument gives nice appearance.

Comment: FYI for full height band, use ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf